# Error connecting to SQL Server using PDO in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

These are the few lines of code that I used to try to connect to a SQL Server.

```
$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$database = "";
$port = "1433";
try {
    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$servername,$port;Database=$database;ConnectionPooling=0", $username, $password,
        array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        )
    );
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo ("Error connecting to SQL Server: " . $e->getMessage());
}
```

After running it, this error came out.

> Error connecting to SQL Server: SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: An unsupported attribute was designated on the PDO object.

May I know what does this mean and any suggestions on how to solve it?

Comment: why you wrote this: PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true?

Comment: PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT is not supported.